# timer on server side not according client machine

Tags: c#, asp.net

everyone I have a problem I have a web form which calls a specific function but it can only be called once every 5 minutes. I have tried using ajax timer control but the timer runs differently on different machine, I mean I load the webform in pc1 timmer would automatically call the same function after 5 minutes on pc1 but if I load the webform in pc2 even after a minute of loading in pc1 and hence I would get an error. Long story short is there a way to do everything on server and not on individual client(without using a database).

Comment: Not clear what you already done and what you're trying to achive.

Comment: suppose I hosted a webform with a variable x with value 20 and I want to update its value after every 2 minutes by 5. now I visit my webform from pc1 so after 2 minutes its value will be 25 after 4 minutes it will be 30, after 4 minutes I decide to check the value of variable x from pc2 so now when i visit my webform it again displays the value of x=20 and would update it again as per the criteria. What i want is if the value of x=30 in pc1 then its value should be same in pc2 as well

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Quartz.Net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/), which is a scheduler.

You can simply schedule a Job to run every 5 minutes and do whatever you need to.

Something like this:

```
// define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
    .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
    .Build();

// Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 10 seconds
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
    .StartNow()
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
        .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
        .RepeatForever())
    .Build();

// Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

And HelloJob:

```
public class HelloJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Greetings from HelloJob!");
    }
}
```